# How to sort Y-Axis's values - Google Charts (server side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I try to use Google Charts in one of my projects. Everything works pretty good, but my Y-Axis is completely unsorted. I am using my DB data(server side)

This is the actual code I use to display my chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([      
      ['gisement', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4', 'element5', 'element6'],

    <?php     
        $result = $pdo->query ("SELECT            
                gisement.nom_gisement AS gisement,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element1,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element2,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element3,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element4,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element5,
                SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS element6
        FROM mesure , puits, niveau , gisement
        where mesure.cm = puits.cm
        and mesure.num_niveau = niveau.id_niveau
        and gisement.id_gisement = puits.num_gisement
        group by gisement.nom_gisement");

        foreach($result AS $row) {
            echo "['".$row['gisement']."','".$row['element1']."','".$row['element2']."','".$row['element3']."','".$row['element4']."','".$row['element5']."','".$row['element6']."'], ";           
        }
    ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: 'Nombres de puits annalysés en chaque gisement' }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));  
  }
```

```
 <div id='columnchart_material' style=' width: 600px; height: 350px;' class='col-md-offset-3'  ></div>
```

The result looks a bit strange, I think the values for the Y-Axis aren't sorted but are taken as they come in.

[Here's my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wnr2.png)

I hope someone can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the values in your data should be numbers, instead of strings, here...

```
echo "['".$row['gisement']."','".$row['element1']."','".$row['element2']."','".$row['element3']."','".$row['element4']."','".$row['element5']."','".$row['element6']."'], ";
```

remove the single quotes from the value columns...

```
echo "['".$row['gisement']."',".$row['element1'].",".$row['element2'].",".$row['element3'].",".$row['element4'].",".$row['element5'].",".$row['element6']."], ";
```